# SAS/SQL Date Time Issue

Tags: datetime, sas

I am trying to split a date time variable into date and time.

The variable `VitalSignTakenDateTime` looks like:

```
09JUN2010:08:05:00.000
```

Normally I use the code

```
data ex2;
set ex1;
specdate=scan(VitalSignTakenDateTime, 1, "");
spectime=scan(VitalSignTakenDateTime, 2, "");
run;
```

But that is not going to work for this since they are separated by a colon instead of a space. Does anyone know of a solution.

Comment: What does the question have to do with SQL?  If nothing, remove it from the tags and the title.

Comment: Because you can use a lot of SQL coding in sas.

Comment: Your code is a data step, not `proc sql`.  Hence, "sas" is an appropriate tag, but not "sql".  If you are going to include SQL, you should generally include the database you are using as well.

Comment: But I don't mind using proc sql...the database was originally a SQL database that I brought into SAS. In sas the date time has the format of Datetime22.3

Answer (score 2):

Use datepart and timepart:

```
 data _null_;
      dt='09JUN2010:08:05:00.000'dt;
      date=datepart(dt);
      time=timepart(dt);
      put date=date9. time=time10.;
    run;
```

Comment: You might add an example of converting a string to a datetime, since it's apparent from the OP's regular code that this may be a string.

Answer (score 1):

While I largely agree with using INPUT to get this most efficiently, or SUBSTR since the position is likely fixed, the most comparable result to your code is to use `CALL SCAN`.

`CALL SCAN` is like `SCAN` except it returns the position and length of the string (meaning, the position of the first character of the word plus the length of that word), meaning you can then use `SUBSTR` to get the word *and* the parts after (or before) the word.

As an example:

```
data ex2;
  input 
    @1 VitalSignTakenDateTime $18.;
  call scan(VitalSignTakenDateTime,1,pos,len,':');
  specdate=substr(VitalSignTakenDateTime,1,len);
  spectime=substr(VitalSignTakenDateTime,len+2);
  put _all_;
datalines;
09JUN2010:08:05:00.000
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string and fixed length you can always use SUBSTR, but using input to convert the value to a datetime and then DATEPART and TIMEPART are the best options.